# Extracting the data between paranthesis and put the resulting value in another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to extract the data between parenthesis from the below dataframe and put the resulting value in a new column. If there are no parenthesis in the column data then we can leave them empty.

```
                                           Data
0                      The city is far (RANDOM)
1           Omega Fatty Acid is good for health
2                  Name of the fruit is (MANGO)
3  The producer had given man good films (GOOD)
4           This summer has a very good (Offer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str.extract` with a regex group where we define everything between paranthesis:

```
df['Newcol'] = df['Data'].str.extract('\((.*)\)')
```

```
                                           Data  Newcol
0                      The city is far (RANDOM)  RANDOM
1           Omega Fatty Acid is good for health     NaN
2                  Name of the fruit is (MANGO)   MANGO
3  The producer had given man good films (GOOD)    GOOD
4           This summer has a very good (Offer)   Offer
```